# Pasar datos de una fila seleccionada de un datagridview a una tabla de SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, datagrid

Buenas comunidad espero esten muy bien. 
Mi duda es la siguiente:
Tengo un datagridview en el cuál cargo cierta información de acuerdo a una búsqueda que realizo, de ese datagridview puedo seleccionar 1, 2, 3 o todas las filas si asi lo quiero. Ahora bien yo quiero el que al presionar un boton poder almacenar la(s) fila(s) que yo seleccione del datagridview en una tabla de SQL. 
Lo que pasa es que no sé como hacer para poder obtener **solo y únicamente** los valores de la(s) fila(s) que yo seleccione y asi poder guardarlos en la base de datos.

Resumiendo: como se puede pasar el valor de 1 sola fila seleccionada (o todas las que el usuario seleccione) de un datagridview a una tabla en SQL

Comment: debes de colocar tu codigo, si utilizas algun orm o ado, cada uno tiene un procedimiento diferente de hacerlo. para guiarnos de tu codigo y darte una respuesta mas util

Answer (score 0):

en las propiedades de tu DataGridView vas a marcar en Modo de seleccion = FullSelectedRow para que te permita seleccionar todos los valores de tu fila.

Posterior a eso, en el metodo CellClick de tu DataGridView vas a agregar el siguiente codigo:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, 
               DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
     //Teniendo en cuenta que DataGridView1 es tu DataGridView.
     DataGridViewRow fila = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

     //Supongamos que tengo el campo nombre en mi DataGridView
     String nombre = Convert.ToString(fila.Cells["nombre"].Value);
     //Ahi extrage el valor de la columna uno por ejemplo, de la misma forma tu lo haras para todos tus campos.

}
```

Posteriormente insertaras tus datos con una consulta, pasando como parametros tus valores extraidos de la fila.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgv in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
if (Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Cells[0].Value) == 1) //Fila seleccionada, yo lo hice con un checkbox
dt.Rows.Add(dgv.Cells[1].Value, dgv.Cells[2].Value, dgv.Cells[3].Value); //Agrega valores de cada columna
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dare una solucion. en este caso es utiliando un micro-ORM (Dapper)

```
public partial class AdressBokPerson
    {
        public long Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string LastName{ get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
    }

 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
   // puedes selecionar el row y convertir el objeto DataBoundItem a un tipo especificado:
AdressBokPerson currentObject = (AdressBokPerson)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;



}

void insert(){

// una vez realizado tu conexion e instalado dapper

// con dapper nos permite mappear la informacion que nosotros deseemos.
// este es el metodo de insertar.
var Result = Conexion.Execute("INSERT INTO AdressBokPerson ( Name, LastName, Mail )
VALUES (@Name, @LastName, @Mail )", currentObject );

Console.WriteLine(Result);
}
```

Este es una forma de realizarlo. espero haberte ayudado